# Flutter: ListView widget values reset when scrolling

Tags: flutter

I have a ListView with some widgets, and when I scroll up/down the widgets reset their states.

[I followed this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699781/how-to-maintain-the-state-of-widget-in-listview), but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```html
class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
    
  Duration _dateClockInitial = Duration.zero; // used to save data from one of the widgets inside ListView
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext contextBuild) {
    super.build(context);
    return ListView(); /*Some widgets*/
  }

    @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: you need to save the state(like selection) of each items on item change/selection and build your ui based on the data which will persist even when you scroll and ui rebuilds.

Comment: I tried that, and while the data inside my variable retains the value of my wiget inside ListView, the UI itself resets itself (for example, I use a time picker, and store the value inside '_dateClockInitial': the variable retains the time I set, while the UI resets to 0:00 when scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

[Found a solution here by Hamid Salehi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63856438/in-listview-on-scrolling-down-loosing-data-in-flutter)

Before:

```html
Form(
    child: ListView(
        children: [ ... ],
    ),
),
```

After:

```html
Form(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            children: [ ... ],
        ),
    ),
),
```